# issue about partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have a view like below.

[image]

there is a column named "Durum". I set the record's value to online or offline with this. I change this value on this page. When I click online image, it becomes offline. I make this using ajax like below:

```
  @foreach(var item in Model)  
  {
   ........
   ........
  @if (item.Online == true)
  {<img   id="img_online_@item.Id" src="/Areas/Admin/Content/images/icons/online.png" class="cursorpointer" title="Offline yap" onclick="SetOnlineStatus('/Bank/EditStatus',@item.Id)" />}
 else{<img id="img_online_@item.Id" src="/Areas/Admin/Content/images/icons/offline.png" class="cursorpointer" title="Online yap" onclick="SetOnlineStatus('/Bank/EditStatus',@item.Id)" />}

  }
```

I write above code every page. So I want to put this online/offline part to the partial view.
I want to put this online/offline state to a partial view. I need to send Id and Online values to partial. I tried to send two parmeter to partial view, but I could not. Can anyone giv me an idea about this issue?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view:

```
@Html.Partial("NamePartialView", item)
```

In your partial view:

```
@model YourNameSpace.Item
@{
   var id = Mode.Online ? Mode.kId : Mode.Id;
   var idTag = string.Format("img_online_{0}", id);
   var title = Mode.Online ? "Onffline yap" : "Online yap"; 
   var srcimg = string.Format("/Areas/Admin/Content/images/icons/{0}", Mode.Online ? "online.png" : "offline.png");
}

<img id="@idTag" src="@srcimg" 
     class="cursorpointer" title="@title"
     onclick="SetOnlineStatus('/Bank/EditStatus', @id)" />
```

**Edit for comment**

```
@foreach(var item in Model)  
{
    Html.Partial("NamePartialView", item);
}
```

Comment: I made some correction on my question. I want to ask you one thing about taking the "item" from partial. How can I take item on the partial.For example, in one form, item will come from Category model, and item will come from Article model in another form.

Comment: I hope understand your question, you send de object `item` in the second parameter of method `Partial` in `Html helper`.

Answer (score 0):

Define the model class for your partial view as you have for the main view, set it to the type of your "item" class and call the renderer:

```
@{
    RenderPartial("..partialName...", item);
}
```